# UserControl inside DataList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, datalist

I have a UserControl inside DataList, I fill the controls inside the usercontrol according to the PrimeryKey of the DataList's data. At first load program behaves as expected but when user changes page index all the MessageID's returns 0, most probably value coming with 
 <%# Eval("id").toString()%> is lost. I dont want to hard code the usercontrol because i used it in many place in the project, it makes the code maintainable. How can i correct this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

My code is below:

```
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="658px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000; font-size: medium; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma">
                            <%# Eval("hadding") +" ["+Eval("startTime")+" - "+Eval("endTime")+"]"%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma">
                            <%# Eval("location") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <uc1:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server" MessageID='<%# Eval("id").toString()%>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnfirst" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="<<" Height="31px"
                        Width="43px" OnClick="btnfirst_Click" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnprevious" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="<" Height="31px"
                        Width="43px" OnClick="btnprevious_Click" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text=">" Height="31px"
                        Width="43px" OnClick="btnnext_Click" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnlast" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text=">>" Height="31px"
                        Width="43px" OnClick="btnlast_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and my user control:

```
Partial Class MyUserControl
  Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

  Private _messageID As Integer

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (_messageID > 0) Then
        Fill(_messageID)
    End If
  End Sub


  Public Property MessageID As Integer
    Get
        Return _messageID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _messageID = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected Sub Fill(messageID As Integer)
    'Some code
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the usercontrol as such:

```
Partial Class MyUserControl
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Property MessageID As Integer
    Get
        Return 0
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        Fill(value)
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Fill(messageID As Integer)
    'Some code
End Sub

End Class
```

As jbl said, this is because of the page lifecycle. OnPageIndexChange event of an ASPxDataview or on your custom PageIndexChange event for asp.net DataList, code work as such:

1. DataList (or ASPxDataview ) Load
2. UserControl Property setting
3. UserControl Load
4. PageIndexChange event
5. UserControl Load
6. UserControl Property setting

That's why on UserControl.Load Property is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without looking at the whole page lifecycle, but you may try to store the `MessageId` in your control's `ViewState`, like this :

```
  Public Property MessageID As Integer
    Get
      If (Me.ViewState("VSMessageID") IsNot Nothing) Then
         return CType(Me.ViewState("VSMessageID "), Integer)
      else 
         return 0 // arbitrary value
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer)
       Me.ViewState.Add("VSMessageID", value)
    End Set
  End Property
```

Then :

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (MessageID > 0) Then
        Fill(MessageID )
    End If
  End Sub
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Sorry if bad VB.Net syntax

Comment: Yes! It is because of page lifecycle. Thank you for quick response.